# Qual a tradução correta de "shipping address" e "billing address" para o português europeu?

Tags: tradução-inglês, português-europeu, significado-em-contexto

As seguintes traduções estão corretas no português europeu?

*Shipping Address* -> *Endereço de Envio*

*Billing Address* -> *Endereço de Faturamento*

Qual é a diferença entre *"Endereço de Envio"* e *"Endereço de Entrega"*?
Qual é melhor para você?

Comment: Em pt-BR diríamos "endereço do destinatário" e "endereço para cobrança".   Mas há quem diga "endereço para entrega", principalmente em se tratando de compras pela Internet.  Já "endereço de envio" não me parece idiomático, embora seja compreendido.

Comment: billing é faturamento/ção. Sem nenhuma dúvida. shipping é o destino/átario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendo que `Endereco de entrega` é o endereço do destinatário. `Endereço de envio` pode ter uma interpretação dúbia para remetente ou destinatário, afinal quem envia é o remetente.

Para Billing Address eu usaria `Endereço de cobrança`. Para mim, faturamento tem uma conotação corporativa, possivelmente não compreensível para pessoas físicas.

Comment: Acho que endereço de Cobrança é diferente de endereço de Faturamento. No Brasil, até concordo que Cobrança e faturamento se misturam, principalmente para pessoas físicas. Mas em Portugal, vejo diferente. Endereço de Faturamento é o meio mais usado. E não há endereço de Cobrança em Portugal, já que normalmente a cobrança não é enviada por correio.

Comment: @Peixoto mas não deve constar um endereço no documento de cobrança?

Comment: @Peixoto, será que a palavra que ouves mais em Portugal não é *faturação* em vez de *faturamento*? :)

Comment: @Jacinto, com certeza estás correto. Faturação é mais usado.

Answer (score 1):

No Google encontro com mais frequência "endereço de entrega" em sites portugueses, que também me soa melhor (mas sou falante de pt-BR). Exemplos: [Apple](https://www.apple.com/pt/shop/help/shipping_delivery) e [DHL.pt](https://www.dhl.pt/content/dam/downloads/pt/express/pt/shipping/rate_guides/dhl_express_rate_transit_guide_pt_pt.pdf).

Comment: endereço de entrega pode ser: where a shipment or package is delivered.